# Не работает приложение на Android 4

Tags: android

Приложение коннектится к интернету в отдельном потоке. На андроид 3.2 всё отлично работает без сбоев. Решила потестить на 4м андроиде - запускается, начинает коннект и виснет - потом падает по таймауту. В чём может быть проблема?

```
class Samo_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
private String TAG = "Samo_AsyncTask";

protected void onPreExecute() {

  super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... url) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Read JSON started");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new  URL(url[0]).openStream();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Samo_Data.error = "Server not available";
    }
    try {
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        final String jsonText = Samo_Connect.readAll(rd);
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"InputStream is closed");
    }
  return null;
}
```

}

**UDPATE**
Большое спасибо за помощь! Ещё не всё заработало, но я хотя бы теперь знаю в чем проблема) У меня действительно один таск вызывал другой, пока сделала так:

```
ASyncTask<Void,Void,Void> my_task = new ASyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() { ... };
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    my_task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
else
    my_task.execute((Void[])null);
```

А потом перепишу на Thred.
Я зациклилась на версии API и была просто в ступоре, еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Штатный телепат в отпуске. Попробуйте описать проблему более подробно, а лучше - приведите код, в котором вы коннектитесь и интернету.

Comment: Поправила, простите.

Comment: Действуйте стандартным способом. В коде наставляете логирование, буквально через строку (при этом можно выводить что-то в стиле "mark1", "mark2". Потом запускаете и получаете "трассу выполнения". В результате Вы будете знать +-2-3 строки, где зависает (либо просто выходит). Дальше либо сами поймете, где застопорилось, либо уже здесь опубликуете.

Comment: Он заходит только в preExecute, а в doInBackground почему-то нет(

03-21 08:33:44.840: D/Samo_AsyncTask(1808): onPreExecute()
03-21 08:33:45.248: W/Trace(1808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-21 08:33:45.309: I/Choreographer(1808): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-21 08:33:45.309: W/Trace(1808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-21 08:33:45.309: W/Trace(1808): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Comment: Из этих всех сообщений полезное только одно.

Тогда временно удалите все содержимое `doInBackground` (или закомментируйте) и вставьте туда просто вывод в лог - чтобы исключить влияние внешних фактов.

Я надеюсь, `execute` Вы вызываете?

Comment: Конечно я вызываю execute, на андроид 3.2 всё отлично работает.

Закомментировала. В doInBackground вообще не заходит.

Comment: а на реальном устройстве пробовали?

Comment: Пробовала, на 3.2 работает, на 4 - нет =(
На 2.2 работает частично (загрузка из сети работает, некоторые другие штуки нет)

Comment: изучите эти два вопроса - [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119627/android-sdk-asynctask-doinbackground-not-running-subclass) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328645/asynctask-called-from-handler-will-not-execute-doinbackground/10406894#10406894). Там у людей такие же проблемы и есть решения.